# Unsure as to where to start any help would be appreciated

Tags: combinatorics

Let $G = (V,E)$ be a graph and let $M_1,M_2 ⊂ E$ be two maximum matchings in $G$. Show that any path in $G$ whose edges alternate between $M_1$ and $M_2$ and is maximal with respect to this property must contain equal number of edges from $M_1$ and $M_2$.

Comment: I'm a bit more self taught, but it almost seems like you could rewrite that as $G=(X,Y)$, and use M 1 and 2 as like intercepts along Y (E). If you say like G forms something like a sine graph (or the weird pointy one), then what your trying to show seems to be alot easier, although I don't know how or if you could expand that to every graph G though.

Comment: Is this G finite?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one possible approach.

Suppose such a maximal path does not contain an equal number of edges from $M_1$ and $M_2$, and then derive a contradiction to the assumption that $M_1$ and $M_2$ are both maximum matchings (by showing that you can increase the size of either $M_1$ or $M_2$).