# can two different maximum matchings M1 and M2 for a graph G = (V,E) share some of the same matchings?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, matching-theory

Let G = (V,E) be a graph and let M1,M2 ⊂ E be two maximum matchings in G. Show that any path in G whose edges alternate between M1 and M2 and is maximal with respect to this property must contain equal number of edges from M1 and M2.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4128418/unsure-as-to-where-to-start-any-help-would-be-appreciated/4128458?r=SearchResults#4128458

Answer (score 0):

Let P:v1-v2-...-vn be a path in G whose edges alternate between matchings M1 and M2 and P cannot be extended and still have that property.  If P has an even number of edges then it does have just as many edges in M1 as in M2.  We can show that P does not have an odd number of edges as follows:
Suppose P starts and ends with edges in M1. The edges of M2 that are NOT on P must be disjoint from P, that is, they can't have a vertex that lies on P.  Let M3 be the matching made by taking the union of the set of edges of M1 lying on P and the set of edges in M2 NOT lying on P.  Note that M3 is a larger matching than M1 or M2 contradicting the fact that M1 and M2 are maximum.

Comment: I am assuming here that the path can close in on itself (form a cycle) because otherwise, an even cycle can have an alternating M1-M2 path of maximum length that is of odd length.